# Can I do multiple regression on a total sample size of 30 (3 groups of 10 each)?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, prediction, psychology

My data is subdivided into 3 groups each of size 10, g1 (grandparents), g2 (parents), and g3 (grandchildren).

I am trying to understand the variance in level of subjective well-being (independent variable having 11 domains) experienced by all three generations, as predicted by intergenerational solidarity (dependent variable having 6 domains) and quality of life of these generations (dependent variable having 10 domains), so there are 11 independent variables and around 16 dependent variables in total for each group.

I wish to study the variance in each subjective well-being domain individually for g1, g2 and g3, as predicted by these 16 dependent variables.

Can I use multiple regression or do I need to use a non-parametric test, given my sample size is small? If so which non-parametric test?

Comment: This isn't very clear. The term _dependent variables_ refers to variables that are being predicted, but you seem to be using it for predictors. But if you have 16 predictors then 30 is still far too small a sample for comfort in multiple regression and 10 impossible. You need to be much more selective in your model choices.

Comment: hmmm, yes dependent variable is the outcome variable. can u suggest which non-parametric test will best suit my sample

Comment: I know of no non-parametric analogue to multiple regression and even if it existed it would presumably have the same limitation.